# If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is bijective in $V\subseteq X$ then $f[U\cap V]=f[U]\cap f[V]$ for any $U\subseteq X$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**Statement**

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is bijective in $V\subseteq X$ then $f[U\cap V]=f[U]\cap f[V]$ for any $U\subseteq X$.

So the statement is surely true when $U\subseteq V$ but unfortunately when this does not occur, I didn't find a counterexample that shows the contrary of what I claim. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :** Consider $f : [-1,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$, with $U=[0,1]$ and $V=[-1,0]$.

Comment: $f(-1) = f(1)$, so $f$ is not bijective.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin In the question, $f$ has to be bijective on $V$ only. Of course otherwise, the equality is true.